# POST json request to Solr with cursorMark in request

Tags: solr, lucene

Is it possible to include `cursorMark` value in POST request's body instead of sending it as query string parameter?

The following query:

```
{"query":"val:abc","limit":10,"cursorMark":"*","sort":"id asc"}
```

returns an error with the message: *"Unknown top-level key in JSON request : cursorMark"*

Comment: how do you send this request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Solr Json Request API documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/json-request-api.html), every query string parameter has a corresponding POST request parameter in **JSON** API, e.g. *q -> query*, *start -> offset*, etc.

However, there is no equivalent parameter for *cursorMark* query string parameter.

The best solution I am aware of is changing request type from *application/json* to *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* which allows using query string parameters in POST request's body. The reason why I was using *application/json* was to get json response, but it turns that it is controlled by *wt=json* parameter.

1. Changed query uri to: http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/select?wt=json
2. Changed POST request parameters back to query string counterparts, i.e. q, start, rows, etc.
3. UrlEncoded the query string.
4. Put the encoded query string in POST body.
5. Changed request content type to *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can you please add code snippet as an example? I am not sure how to set content-type parameter in solr query using solrJ.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_7/json-request-api.html#passing-parameters-via-json says that you can augment a JSON-based POST with non-JSON params. I got this to work in 2022 with a JSON query that includes `"params": {"cursorMark": "*"}`, without needing to resort to changing the request type (as suggested in the accepted answer).