# Solr: Group via JSON request via HTTP POST

Tags: json, post, solr

I am trying to use Solr's `result grouping` by posting JSON formatted query to the `/query` request handler (e.g. via the `Documents` tab in Solr's admin UI; use set request handler to `/query`)

The query is simple:

```
{
  "query":"Description:keyword",
  "offset":0,
  "limit":20
}
```

All samples I found use HTTP GET, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=id,name&q=solr+memory&group=true&group.field=manu_exact
```

When I try to add JSON field `group`, `groups`, `grouping` or something, the error message is always the same:

```
Unknown top-level key in JSON request : group...
```

I am aware of the approach provided here: [POST json request to Solr with cursorMark in request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007512/post-json-request-to-solr-with-cursormark-in-request) (post url-encoded data instead of JSON). However, I'd like to avoid that. Any ideas how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am looking for is the `JSON Request API`. Unfortunately, it seems that it is discontinued. In October 2016 [Yonik wrote](http://yonik.com/solr-json-request-api/): "The JSON Request API is currently in it’s infancy – only a few query parameters are supported". The latest official documentation about the API is from 2015: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/JSON+Request+API (and was also created by someone called *Yonik*. Coincidence?!) But it is not mentioned in the current reference guides Apache Solr 6.5/6.6.

So the answer is: *Result grouping* cannot be accessed via a JSON query.
Note: Same is true for the more current *Collapse and Expand components*.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this using the JSON api. Put the `group` stuff inside the `params` part of your request, and then it returns data the same way as the `/select` endpoint. Something like

```
{
  "query":"Description:keyword",
  "offset":0,
  "limit":20,
  "params": {
    "group": true,
    "group.field": "<fieldname>"
  }
}
```

Comment: After reading https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/collapse-and-expand-results.html, you should probably just put `{!collapse field=<field to group by>}` in your `filter`.